# Программа переводчик слов в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, google-translate

Суть программы в том, что она отображает случайное слово на русском языке из словаря и нужно написать его перевод на английском.

У меня получилось, что при каждом запуске только одно слово выходит.

Как сделать, чтобы при любом ответе - правильном или нет, выходило новое слово?

```
translate = {'яблоко': 'apple', "груша": 'pear', 'книга': 'book', 'телефон': 'phone', 'часы': 'clock', 'любовь': 'love'}
word = random.choice(list(translate.keys()))


def test():
    global window
    if entry.get() == translate[word]:
        counter.set(counter.get() + 1)
    else:
        counter_2.set(counter_2.get() + 1)
    if counter_2.get() == 3:
        window.destroy()
        
window = Tk()
counter = IntVar()
counter_2 = IntVar()
frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack()
label = Label(frame, text = 'Переведите на английский слово:')
label.pack()
label_2 = Label(frame, text = word, font="Arial 13") 
label_2.pack()
entry = Entry(frame)
entry.pack()
label_3 = Label(frame, text = 'Верно:')
label_3.pack()
label_4 = Label(frame, textvariable = counter)
label_4.pack()
button = Button(frame, text = 'Проверить', command = test, bg = 'green')
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не смог воспроизвести ваш пример, но я вам покажу другой пример, попробуйте:

```
import random
import googletrans                                # pip install googletrans
import textblob                                   # pip install textblob
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox


root = Tk()
root.title('Translator')
root.iconbitmap('music.ico')
root.geometry("880x300")

def translate_it():
    tr_text = translated_text.get(1.0, END).strip().lower()
    if not tr_text:
        messagebox.showerror("Внимание", "Введите ваш вариант перевода.")
        return

    try:
        # Получение языков из ключей словаря
        for key, value in languages.items():
            if (value == original_combo.get()):
                from_language_key = key

        # Get the To Language Key
        for key, value in languages.items():
            if (value == translated_combo.get()):
                to_language_key = key

        # Turn Original Text into a TextBlob
        words = textblob.TextBlob(original_text.get(1.0, END))

        # Translate Text
        words = words.translate(from_lang=from_language_key , to=to_language_key)

        if tr_text == words.lower():
            messagebox.showinfo("Успех", "Это правильный перевод.")
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Внимание", f"Это НЕ правильный перевод. ({words})")

        translated_text.delete(1.0, END)
        new_word()

    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Translator Error: ", e)

def clear():
    # Clear the text boxes
    original_text.delete(1.0, END)
    translated_text.delete(1.0, END)
    new_word()

# Получить список языков из GoogleTrans
languages = googletrans.LANGUAGES
# Преобразовать в список
language_list = list(languages.values())

original_text = Text(root, height=10, width=40)
original_text.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20, padx=10)

translated_text = Text(root, height=10, width=40)
translated_text.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=20, padx=10)

translate_button = Button(
    root, 
    text="Translate!", 
    font=("Helvetica", 24), 
    command=translate_it
)
translate_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

original_combo = ttk.Combobox(root, width=50, value=language_list)
original_combo.current(77)
original_combo.grid(row=1, column=0)

translated_combo = ttk.Combobox(root, width=50, value=language_list)
translated_combo.current(21)
translated_combo.grid(row=1, column=2)

# Clear button
clear_button = Button(root, text="Clear", command=clear)
clear_button.grid(row=2, column=1)


text = '''
Суть программа что она отображает случайное слово  русский язык 
словарь нужно писать перевод английский получилось 
что при каждый запуск только одно слово выходит 
Как сделать чтобы любой ответ правильно или нет выход новое слово
Привет мир
'''
words = text.split()

def new_word():
    word = random.choice(words)
    original_text.delete(1.0, END)
    original_text.insert(1.0, word)
    
new_word()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваш ответ. Я так же понял, что мне нужно было добавить в функцию test.                                                                                    `def test():
    global window
    global word
    if entry.get() == translate[word]:
        counter.set(counter.get() + 1)
        word = random.choice(list(translate.keys()))
        label_2.config(text = word)
    else:
        counter_2.set(counter_2.get() + 1)
    if counter_2.get() == 3:
        window.destroy()`

Comment: @ВячеславМамаев пожалуйста. Я не проверял ваше приложение, т.к. оно было не полное, а сразу предложил свой вариант.